# Django ORM: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've added class methods for the model. After adding them, it stopped working, gives me a type error. Migrations also don't work. These classes calculate the price with and without discount. Now quantity throws an error, suddenly becoming a 'list' object

models

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Item" + str(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    @classmethod
    def get_total_quantity_for_product(cls, product):
        return cls.objects.filter(product=product).aggregate(total_quantity=models.Sum('quantity'))[
            'total_quantity'] or 0

    @staticmethod
    def get_average_price():
        return OrderItem.objects.aggregate(average_price=models.Avg('price'))['average_price']
```

admin.py code

```
import csv
import datetime

from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import Order, OrderItem, ShippingAddress


def export_paid_to_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    content_disposition = f"attachment; filename=Paid{opts.verbose_name}.csv"
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = content_disposition
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    fields = [
        field
        for field in opts.get_fields()
        if not field.many_to_many and not field.one_to_many
    ]
    writer.writerow([field.verbose_name for field in fields])
    for obj in queryset:
        if not getattr(obj, "paid"):
            continue
        data_row = []
        for field in fields:
            value = getattr(obj, field.name)
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value = value.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            data_row.append(value)
        writer.writerow(data_row)
    return response


export_paid_to_csv.short_description = "Export Paid to CSV"


def export_not_paid_to_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    content_disposition = f"attachment; filename=NotPaid{opts.verbose_name}.csv"
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = content_disposition
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    fields = [
        field
        for field in opts.get_fields()
        if not field.many_to_many and not field.one_to_many
    ]
    writer.writerow([field.verbose_name for field in fields])
    for obj in queryset:
        if getattr(obj, "paid"):
            continue
        data_row = []
        for field in fields:
            value = getattr(obj, field.name)
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value = value.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            data_row.append(value)
        writer.writerow(data_row)
    return response


export_not_paid_to_csv.short_description = "Export Not Paid to CSV"


def order_pdf(obj):
    url = reverse('payment:admin_order_pdf', args=[obj.id])
    return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}">PDF</a>')


order_pdf.short_description = 'Invoice'


class ShippingAdressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('full_name_bold', 'user', 'email', 'country', 'city', 'index')
    empty_value_display = "-empty-"
    list_display_links = ('full_name_bold',)
    list_filter = ('user', 'country', 'city')

    @admin.display(description="Full Name", empty_value="Noname")
    def full_name_bold(self, obj):
        return format_html("<b style='font-weight: bold;'>{}</b>", obj.full_name)


class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    extra = 0

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['price', 'product', "quantity", "user"]
        return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'shipping_address', 'amount',
                    'created', 'updated', 'paid', 'discount', order_pdf
                    ]
    list_filter = ['paid', 'updated', 'created', ]
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]
    list_per_page = 15
    list_display_links = ['id', 'user']
    actions = [export_paid_to_csv, export_not_paid_to_csv]


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
admin.site.register(ShippingAddress, ShippingAdressAdmin)
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\payment\models.py", line 81, in <module>
    class OrderItem(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\whydiekrekerzz\PycharmProjects\ShopDjango\payment\models.py", line 83, in OrderItem
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What should i do to fix this error? Rollback also not working

Comment: The error message says `quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)` is on line 83, which does not match the posted code.  I suspect there is some other code in `models.py` that is causing the problem.  Please post that entire file.

Comment: The only way that the last line in your traceback could have produced that specific error is if you had overwritten `models.IntegerField` with a list.  Try searching for `models.IntegerField = [` to find where this happened.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally added the '=' above, and redefined the IntegerField. Thanks, it seriously helped me